# Turn.js Step or Gradual Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

In turn.js, how to zoom in and zoomout by step. For Example please checkout this Demo:

http://codecanyon.net/item/wowbook-create-ebooks-with-page-flip/full_screen_preview/1791563

The code below works but zooms at once:

```
$('.magazine-viewport').zoom({
    flipbook: $('.magazine'),
    max: 3,
    when:{
        tap: function(event){
            if ($(this).zoom("value")==1) {
                $(this).zoom("zoomIn", event);
            } else {
                $(this).zoom("zoomOut");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You just need Zooming feature from that????

Comment: Both zoomin and zoomout.I meant when I click on the Zoomin button, it should zoom gradually and same with zoomout.

Comment: did you find a solution? same problem some years later here, thank you!